# Rails not including require_tree for javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have been trying for many hours to execute a simple console and alert message in javascript in my rails application, after check that more complex javascript (coffee) code does not work. The only way in which I am able to print something is putting the code in the application.js. Here are the main files in my application:

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'haml', "~> 4.0.4"
gem 'i18n', '~> 0.6.9'
```

assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

assets/javascripts/example.coffee

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log( "pRUEBAEFADF")
});
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module HotelAbadi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :es

    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.paths << "#{ Rails.root }/app/assets/fonts"

    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
HotelAbadi::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
end
```

I have also tried to add the file manually but it does not execute anything. I can not find more pages which talks about this problem. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I have updated the version from 3.2.0 to 3.2.15 and the problem solve.

Comment: Your manifest file loads `jquery` & `jquery_ujs`. Can you make sure appropriate those jquery files are properly loaded ? If not (missing, not in path), your coffeescript file won't be even loaded.

Comment: The problem was with the version of rails. I have been using 3.2.0 and now I have updated it to 3.2.15 and the problem solve suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

Your `assets/javascripts/example.coffee` is not Coffeescript, is Javascript. Rename the file to `assets/javascripts/example.js` or translate the code to Coffeescript. Also, if you prefer to translate it to Coffeescript, the name should be `assets/javascripts/example.js.coffee`.

Comment: I have tried but still not working. I am trying the solution of Nelson but the install process is too slow (I don't know why). It's trying to install libv8 (10 minutes now...).

Answer (score -2):

It's important to add 'therubyracer' gem.

Add this line in the assets group

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

More information here: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer

Comment: After installing, still not working. When I load the page, not print anything. I have changed the the code of the example.js, so now its name is example.coffee and it uses coffee syntax ( $(document).ready -> console.log "LOADED" ).

Comment: if he didn't have a JS runtime installed, his server wouldn't even start.